# How to use Django with MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel, django-mongodb-engine

Can someone tell me how to use Django MongoDB Engine?

I have followed the instructions here: http://django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html

All I get is this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongodb_engine.mongodb' isn't an available database backend. 
Try using django.db.backends.XXX, where XXX is one of:
    'dummy', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named django_mongodb_engine.mongodb.base
```

Answer (score 4):

Should be `django_mongodb_engine`, not `django_mongodb_engine.mongodb`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the location where you downloaded the package is not in your `PYTHONPATH`, so django cannot import it.

If you followed those instructions, you need to run your application from the virtualenv you created (`myproject` in the example).

Or, you need to add it to your `PYTHONPATH` to make sure django can import it.

You should be able to run the python interactive shell and execute `import django_mongodb_engine.mongodb` without any errors.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer with here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699521/django-mongodb-i-cannot-update

Essentially one will need to install:

•django-mongodb-engine

•pymongo

•django-nonrel

•djangotoolbox

•mongoengine

Comment: either Django MongoDB Engine or MongoEngine, not both

Comment: I was unable to get it to work without installing them both. I am about to do a re installation, I will confirm this for everyone myself.